# Rockshox Pike 351 closest mainline model?

Tags: fork, compatibility

I'm looking at getting some second-hand Rockshox Pike 351 forks that will need some refurbish work doing on them. What mainline model of Rockshox would I be looking at for replacement parts (I think pike 426?) or are the parts specific for only that model?

The part I'm looking at replacing in particular is the damper, anyone know exactly which model of damper I would need for that?

Comment: The 351 being a version made for Specialized?

Comment: Yeah that's the one

Comment: My initial thought is that finding a fork that doesn't need refurb would be cheaper than one that does + cost of refurb.

Comment: It's more for me to learn how to service them. The guy that's selling it says that it needs a new damper but I'll probably start with stripping the lowers and changing seals etc.

I only want to know the damper type etc just in case I do need to refurb the whole thing or if I want to go ahead and try it anyway.